# Jboss eap 5.1 GC JMV options

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I'am using Jboss eap 5.1 with Seam Framework. I want to tune my GC to avoid FullGC. I already using CMS GC. This will be my next configuration on production system:

```
-Xms24g
-Xmx24g
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:NewRatio=4 
-XX:SurvivorRatio=8    
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC 
-XX:+UseParNewGC 
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC  
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly 
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled  
-XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark 
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=68
```

My question is "Do I need to remove this JVM options"?:

```
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
```

if I will add this one:

```
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC
```

or they must stay together?

Answer (score 1):

You can have both sets of the options enabled. But, the `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC` will prevent any SystemGC calls coming from the RMI sessions.

The recommended use is either to disable SystemGC alltogether by using `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC` or at least use the `sun.rmi.dgc.*.gcInterval` flags to control the frequency of the System GC calls (to prevent the SystemGC to occur too often).

I would suggest using the `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC` and observing whether the number of "dead" RMI objects is growing, if yes, then you need to start tuning with the `sun.rmi.dgc.*.gcInterval` flags.

This is all provided that you really want to avoid Full GC, perhaps tolerating a short pause Full GC would not be such a bad idea since you will need them to clean the RMI objects anyway.